# Adding encoding to postForObject call Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest

Im working with latin special caracters like "Teléfono", Variación" this special characters are input of a api rest call.

Im using RestTemplate to make the call, everything works fine but when this parameters are send the api client throws an error related to these words not traveling fine.

here is my code.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
Data attached to the request, Map body and headers.
HttpEntity<TipificacionPrincipalRequest> requestBody = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers);
objTipificacionPrincipalResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(propiedades.restTipificacionPrincipalUrl, requestBody, TipificacionPrincipalResponse.class);
```

As you can see Ive tried

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
```

and also

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
        .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

None of the above code work as you can see in the log file

```
SERVER: AdminServer [ INFO] [02-09-2019 17:54:29.349] (TipificacionRestImpl.java:42) - [ ejecutarAjuste idTx= ] - [generarTipificacionPrincipal] - request = {
  "contactobjid1" : null,
  "siteobjid1" : null,
  "account" : null,
  "phone" : "H6390204",
  "tipo" : "HFC",
  "clase" : "VARIACIÃN - FACTURACIÃN/COBRANZAS",
  "subclase" : "AJUSTE OCC ATENCIÃN CLIENTE",
  "metodoContacto" : "TelÃ©fono",
  "tipoInter" : "Entrante",
  "agente" : "USRWEB",
  "usrProceso" : "USRSIACP",
  "hechoEnUno" : "0",
  "notas" : "Interaccion creada desde el CES por concepto de ajuste por reclamo 1123",
  "flagCaso" : "0",
  "resultado" : "Ninguno",
  "servafect" : null,
  "inconven" : null,
  "servafectCode" : null,
  "inconvenCode" : null,
  "coId" : "112",
  "codPlano" : "112",
  "valor1" : null,
  "valor2" : null
}
SERVER: AdminServer [ INFO] [02-09-2019 17:54:29.349] (TipificacionRestImpl.java:43) - [ ejecutarAjuste idTx= ] - [generarTipificacionPrincipal] - ----------------------------------
```

Still are special characters not recognize.

Update

I've managed to make it work, but the problem seem to be the properties file from I'm reading these values.

I had this keys

```
clase.tipificacion=VARIACIÓN - FACTURACIÓN COBRANZAS
sub.clase.tipificacion=AJUSTE OCC ATENCIÓN CLIENTE
metodo.contacto.tipificacion=Teléfono
```

By changing them to these

```
clase.tipificacion=VARIACI\u00d3N - FACTURACI\u00d3N/COBRANZAS
sub.clase.tipificacion=AJUSTE OCC ATENCI\u00d3N CLIENTE
metodo.contacto.tipificacion=Tel\u00e9fono
```

I can finally see travel the special characters correctly to the client

```
SERVER: AdminServer [ INFO] [02-09-2019 18:44:50.746] (TipificacionRestImpl.java:53) - [ ejecutarAjuste idTx= ] - [generarTipificacionPrincipal] - request = {
  "headers" : {
    "Content-Type" : [ "application/json;charset=UTF-8" ]
  },
  "body" : {
    "contactobjid1" : null,
    "siteobjid1" : null,
    "account" : null,
    "phone" : "H6390204",
    "tipo" : "HFC",
    "clase" : "VARIACIÓN - FACTURACIÓN/COBRANZAS",
    "subclase" : "AJUSTE OCC ATENCIÓN CLIENTE",
    "metodoContacto" : "Teléfono",
    "tipoInter" : "Entrante",
    "agente" : "USRWEB",
    "usrProceso" : "USRSIACP",
    "hechoEnUno" : "0",
    "notas" : "Interaccion creada desde el CES por concepto de ajuste por reclamo 1123",
    "flagCaso" : "0",
    "resultado" : "Ninguno",
    "servafect" : null,
    "inconven" : null,
    "servafectCode" : null,
    "inconvenCode" : null,
    "coId" : "112",
    "codPlano" : "112",
    "valor1" : null,
    "valor2" : null
  }
}
SERVER: AdminServer [ INFO] [02-09-2019 18:44:50.747] (TipificacionRestImpl.java:54) - [ ejecutarAjuste idTx= ] - [generarTipificacionPrincipal] - ----------------------------------
```

Updated question will be How can I read special characters using spring from property file without changing the values.

Hope someone can help

Comment: Are you certain that the problem isn't your log viewer?

Comment: No, since the api client wich I'm calling throws some data error that is directly related to the special characters that are travelling